# Combining two columns into a single map column in hive table

Tags: sql, dictionary, hive, key-value, presto

I have a hive table like

```
    a   b  
-------------
    1   2
    3   4
```

How can I create a map column `c`

```
     c
-----------
    1: 2
    3: 4
```

where column `a` is the keys and column `b` is the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use map() construct in Hive:

```
select map(a,b) as c from mytable
```

In Presto you can use map(array[key], array[value])

```
select map(array[a],array[b]) as c from mytable
```

Or map_agg()

```
select map_agg(a,b) as c from mytable group by a,b
```